# Is there a PHP equivalent function to the Python os.path.normpath()?

Tags: php, python, path

Is there a PHP equivalent function to the Python `os.path.normpath()`?
Or how can i get the **exactly** same functionality in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my 1:1 rewrite of normpath() method from Python's posixpath.py in PHP:

```
function normpath($path)
{
    if (empty($path))
        return '.';

    if (strpos($path, '/') === 0)
        $initial_slashes = true;
    else
        $initial_slashes = false;
    if (
        ($initial_slashes) &&
        (strpos($path, '//') === 0) &&
        (strpos($path, '///') === false)
    )
        $initial_slashes = 2;
    $initial_slashes = (int) $initial_slashes;

    $comps = explode('/', $path);
    $new_comps = array();
    foreach ($comps as $comp)
    {
        if (in_array($comp, array('', '.')))
            continue;
        if (
            ($comp != '..') ||
            (!$initial_slashes && !$new_comps) ||
            ($new_comps && (end($new_comps) == '..'))
        )
            array_push($new_comps, $comp);
        elseif ($new_comps)
            array_pop($new_comps);
    }
    $comps = $new_comps;
    $path = implode('/', $comps);
    if ($initial_slashes)
        $path = str_repeat('/', $initial_slashes) . $path;
    if ($path)
        return $path;
    else
        return '.';
}
```

This will work **exactly** the same as os.path.normpath() in Python

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) command will return a normalized path.  It's similar to a combined version of Python's `os.path.normpath` and `os.path.realpath`.

However, it will also resolve symbolic links.  I'm not sure what you'd do if you didn't want that behavior.

Comment: PHP's realpath would be more like the equivalent of os.path.abspath() or os.path.realpath()

Comment: @Gordon: PHP's realpath is more like a combined version of Python's os.path.normpath and os.path.realpath.

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get to `os.path.normpath()` functionality. Either this or there is no (at least) built-in function for this. It depends on what the OP really needs...

Comment: No, it is not the same. PHP checks what ever this path exist on local computer. Python only calculates path - that is what I need.

Simple test in php and python. PHP: echo realpath('/bin/../lib/'); echo realpath('/bin2/../lib2/'); - will return '/lib' and empty string;

Python: print os.path.normpath('/bin/../lib') -> /lib, print os.path.normpath('/bin2/../lib2') -> /lib2

Comment: @troex: Actually, PHP should return FALSE for the non-existent one.  I don't see any other PHP built-ins that just canonicalize paths, though.